# How do I record internet radio stream from banshee?

Tags: banshee, stream, internet-radio

Maybe present some extension?? I have use banshee 1.9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work for me, and I doubt it will work for you. There is an extension for Banshee to accomplish this, but it normally causes banshee to hang, sometimes crash.

If you are using 1.9 from a ppa, install the community-extensions, and then enable stream recorder. When you go to the radio browser, you can then click on the record button and see if it works for you. If it doesn't work I would suggest using rhythmbox to record.

Comment: I was installed community-extensions and enable stream recorder, and when i open radio browser and pick the stream, banshee was crashed. [ my english so bad :( ]

Comment: your english is fine to me :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue has now been fixed in the developer version. To get it working with the current version, all you have to do is to make sure to configure the StreamRecorder plugin to point to an existing directory before using it, otherwise it will crash.