# How do I record internet radio stream from banshee 2.6.2?

Tags: banshee, internet-radio

I don't have stream-recorder in available plugins. Where can I get it?
There is [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13181/how-do-i-record-internet-radio-stream-from-banshee), but solution doesn't work any more. I have banshee installed from default repository, it's 2.6.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to download the StreamRecorder extension for Banshee.

You can download it from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/banshee-community-extensions).  Make sure that you install common files for banshee-community-extensions first, which also can be downloaded from the same location.

Comment: Thanks. However Banshee now crashes every time at launch. I will look for a workaround later, when I 'll have time